# Add Floats From File And Store As Variable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `.txt` with floats, separated by dots.

File looks like:

```
1.72
2.17
10.72
5.31
```

How can I read the file, add all the floats, and store is as one float variable, so I can print it out later?

Comment: What is the problem? It looks like you forgot to include your [attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: You basically answered yourself: *open file, read, add, print*.  If you are looking for a tutorial or some hand holding, you have the wrong site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to read the text file.

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Obama\Desktop\HalfLife3\floats.txt";
string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

One thing to note about C# is that they are called singles, not floats. This will take all the lines from the text file and add them to a `List<Single>`.

```
List<Single> floats = new List<float>();
foreach (string s in text)
{
    floats.Add(Convert.ToSingle(s));
}
```

Now you have `floats` with all of your values. If you want to print them you can do something like this:

```
foreach (Single s in floats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
}
```